# C# .NET: nested try catch block not handling exception properly

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

To demonstrate Exception Handling, I have intentionally put the wrong table name and null instance to `SqlDataReader dr`. The Inner try block catches the wrong table reference exception `SqlClient.SqlException` but the outer try block fails to catch the `NullReferenceException` on `dr.hasRows`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Exp_Handling
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            //SqlDataReader dr;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=ITEM-S132712\MSSQLSERVER2019;initial catalog=Hotel;integrated security=true");
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Room_Entry1", conn);

                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = null;
                try
                {
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("****" + ex.Message);
                }
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DATA FOUND");
                    while (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.NullReferenceException nullExp)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("##try1###" + nullExp.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Instance is Null for DataReader");
            }
            catch (Exception out_Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("##try2###" + out_Ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Demonstration from Reference https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6055/net-exception-handling-for-database-calls-to-sql-server-with-try-catch-and-finally/

Comment: The instance of `dr` is set on this line: `dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`. I don't think you'll get a NRE on `dr.HasRows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many issues with this code it's hard to know where to start:

- Catching `NullReference` is ridiculous: you won't get one, unless the `ExecuteReader` failed and you caught the `SqlException`, in which case you should just move the `catch (SqlException` to the outside and then you can remove the `catch (NullReferenceException`.
- `conn` `cmd` and `dr` need `using`.
- `while (dr.HasRows)` makes no sense, it should probably be `while (dr.Read())`
- Don't use `SELECT *`, only select the columns you need.
- Don't use `GetString(0)`, instead use the column name.
- Don't hardcode the connection string, instead store it in a settings file

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SomeColumn from Room_Entry1", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DATA FOUND");
                    while (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dr["SomeColumn"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("****" + ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception out_Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("##try2###" + out_Ex.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```